# How to select items in this custom Vaadin combo box that uses an text input element?

Tags: vaadin, watir, watir-classic

[image]

The above pic shows the select list but it's not actually select list, it consist of 'Input' tag, So I tried to set the value using b.text_field.set("argentina") but it only focuses(color changes to yellow) but it's not setting the value, how could I do that?

The code for that select list is given below

```
<div class="v-filterselect v-widget v-has-width v-filterselect-prompt" role="combobox" style="width: 100%;">
  <input tabindex="0" class="v-filterselect-input" id="gwt-uid-17" aria-labelledby="gwt-uid-16" style="width: 100%;" type="text" autocomplete="nope">
  <div class="v-filterselect-button" role="button" aria-hidden="true">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which version of Watir is this problem for? Is it Watir-Classic or Watir-Webdriver as the implementations/problems can be quite different. If Watir-Webdriver, which browser(s) have the problem?

Comment: It will also help to provide an example page that let's us see/reproduce the problem. Usually you can find an example on the libraries webpage. Is it the this [combo box](http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/combo-box)?

Comment: @JustinKo Yes, combo box, you have pointed exact page as well. http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/combo-box I am using watir-classic, not webdriver now, also using IE browser.

Comment: @JustinKo Yes you have pointed out the exact same page in your question " Is it the this combo box? " Can you tell me how could I automate this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that Watir-Classic calls the blur event after setting the value. As a value is not selected from the dropdown, Vaadin considers this as an invalid input and resets it back to "No country selected". You can see the same behaviour when you interact with the combobox manually:

1. Click the text field
2. Type "argentina"
3. Click somewhere else in the page (ie runs the blur event)

To populate the field, you need to select an item from the dropdown. Even though the input field is being cleared, the dropdown does remain (at least when Watir-Classic does it). As a result, we are able to select an item without extra work.

Here is an example using the Vaadin demo page:

```
require 'watir-classic'

browser = Watir::Browser.new
browser.goto('http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/multiple-value/combo-box')

country = 'ARGENTINA'

browser.text_field(aria_labelledby: 'gwt-uid-16').when_present.set(country)
browser.div(id: 'VAADIN_COMBOBOX_OPTIONLIST').span(text: country).when_present.click
```

Note that this will not replicate the exact events generated when a user interacts with the field. However, if you are just using the control, rather than testing the field (ie a Vaadin developer), this is likely sufficient.

Comment: You are simply genius Man! Excellent. Meanwhile I too resolve this problem this way

`b.input(:id,'something').focus
b.input(:id,'something').send_keys 'argentina'
b.send_keys :enter`

But the problem is send_keys need a active window all the time.

Comment: Yeah, I have had to avoid `send_keys` due to its lack of robustness.

Comment: Yes! I continue to automate all the elements from vaadin since I have to undergo a project but I failed to automate this rich text box, http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/text-input/rich-text-area, Can you please guide me how to automate this one as well? Or Do I have to create another question for this?

Comment: `require 'watir'

b=Watir::Browser.start 'http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/text-input/password-field'

b.text_field(:id,'gwt-uid-150').when_present.set 'hi'`

I have written the above code to this password field, but it waits until 60 secs and it throws this errors

` `until': timed out after 60 seconds (Watir::Wait::TimeoutError)`

Comment: It looks like the problem is that the ID attribute is dynamically generated. For example, the code worked for me when I changed the ID to "gwt-uid-11" instead of "gwt-uid-150". For your actual project, you will want to make sure that the developers add unique attributes so that can locate them easier.

Comment: In order to benefit other uses who might run into trying to work with the came custom controls, it would be really useful to have your second question (in comments above) as a stand alone question of it's own.

Comment: @ChuckvanderLinden yes, sure, I will create the separate stand alone post whenever I tend to ask new things.